# Domain of Multivariable Function (xy-plane except circle)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I wanted to know if I am understanding this correctly. The answer is D because when you solve for the intercepts in the denominator they will always be on the xy plane. But if they are not on the xy plane the answer is wrong thereby being a point somewhere on the circle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not well-defined for those $x,y$ for which the denominator $x^{2}+y^{2}-4$ is zero. Thus, the domain of $f$ must be $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}, \hspace{0.1cm} x^{2}+y^{2}=4\}$. But the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2},\hspace{0.1cm} x^{2}+y^{2}=4\}$ is a circle with radius $2$. This is the reason your answer is D.